# Canvas - onClick move object to clicked [x, y] with specified speed

Tags: canvas

I was searching for a solution but couldn't find any good and written in easy way, I hope you can help me out with this problem.

I just want to achieve:
 - - - onClick go perfectly to clicked [x, y] coordinates with specified speed (stored in variable, eg. speed;),

I saw similar questions being asked here but I couldn't understand them, please, if you know the solution, write it in the simplest possible way. Thank you in advance.

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
var cHeight = 500;
var cWidth = 500;

ctx.font = '30px Arial';

var enemyList = {};

var player = {
    x: 50,
    y: 50,
    spdX: 1,
    spdY: 1,
    name: 'P',
    hp: 10
}; 

getDistanceBetweenEntity = function(entity1, entity2) {
    var vx = entity1.x - entity2.x;
    var vy = entity1.y - entity2.y;
    return Math.sqrt(vx*vx+vy*vy);
}

testCollisionEntity = function(entity1, entity2) {
    var distance = getDistanceBetweenEntity(entity1, entity2);
    return distance < 30;
}


enemy = function(id, x, y, spdX, spdY) {
    var enemy = {
        x: x,
        spdX: spdX,
        y: y,
        spdY: spdY,
        name: 'E',
        id: id
    }
    enemyList[id] = enemy;
}


updateEntity = function(entity){
    updateEntityPosition(entity);
    drawEntity(entity);
}

updateEntityPosition = function(entity) {
    entity.x += entity.spdX;
    entity.y += entity.spdY;
    

    if (entity.x < 0 || entity.x > cWidth) {
        entity.spdX = -entity.spdX;
    }
    if (entity.y < 0 || entity.y > cHeight) {
        entity.spdY = -entity.spdY;
    }
}


drawEntity = function(entity) {
    ctx.fillText(entity.name, entity.x, entity.y);
}


 update = function() {

    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cWidth, cHeight);
    
    for(var key in enemyList) { 
        updateEntity(enemyList[key]);
        var isColliding = testCollisionEntity(player, enemyList[key]);
        if(isColliding) {
            // console.log("Colliding!");
        }
    }

    drawEntity(player);

}

enemy('E1', 150, 350, 10, 15);
enemy('E2', 250, 350, 10, -15);
enemy('E3', 250, 150, 10, -8);

setInterval(update, 1000/30);


document.onclick = function(mouse) {
    var mouseX = mouse.clientX;
    var mouseY = mouse.clientY;
    
    while ( mouseX !== player.x && mouseY !== player.y ) {

        if ( mouseX <= player.x ) {
            player.x -= player.spdX;
        } else if ( mouseX >= player.x ) {
            player.x += player.spdX;
        }

        if ( mouseY <= player.y ) {
            player.y -= player.spdY;
        } else if ( mouseY >= player.y ) {
            player.y += player.spdY;
        }

    }
}
```

```css
/*
  I just wanted to achieve:
    - onClick go to clicked [x, y] with SPECIFIED speed which will be stored in variable eg. var speed;
*/
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500" style="margin: 0 auto; border: 1px solid black;"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Moving at fixed speed

Add two properties to the play that are the current target x,y. Make null if no target

```
const player = {
    x: 50,
    y: 50,
    name: 'P',
    hp: 10,        
    targetX : null, // null for no target
    targetY : null,
```

Add a speed value in pixels per frame (60Fps) so 10 pixels per second is 10 / 60

```
    speed : 10 / 60,
```

Add a function that will move the player if there is a target set

```
    update(){
        if(this.targetX !== null){
```

Get the x,y distance to the target, then get the linear distance. If the distance is less than speed then you are there so set the position and null the target

```
            var xd = this.targetX - this.x;
            var yd = this.targetY - this.y;
            var distToTarget = Math.sqrt(xd*xd+yd*yd);
            if(distToTarget<= this.speed){
                 this.x = this.targetX;
                 this.y = this.targetY;
                 this.targetX = this.targetY = null;
            }else {
```

If not there then divide the x,y distance by the linear distance to get a vector that is one unit long.

```
                 xd /= distToTarget;
                 yd /= distToTarget;
```

The length of the vector xd,yd is 1 pixel. We can multiply that by the speed and get the number of pixels to move in x and y to move at that speed

```
                 xd *= this.speed;
                 yd *= this.speed;
```

Update the player pos and end of function and close the object player

```
                 this.x += xd;
                 this.y += yd;
             }
         }
   }
```

You can do the same for the enemies as they are chasing the player you can use the very same function for them but you just set the target to the player. It may pay to have them dumb down a bit so set the targets only every so many frames, or use a random odds test. (see code)

Also it is best to animate with `requestAnimationFrame` rather than `setInterval`.

I have rewritten your code below.

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
var cHeight = 500;
var cWidth = 500;

ctx.font = '30px Arial';

// As you are sharing some functionality I put the shared functions in a separate object
var sharedBehaviour = {
  x: 50,
  y: 50,
  targetX: null, // null for no target
  targetY: null,
  speed: 100 / 60,
  update() {
    if (this.targetX !== null) {
      var xd = this.targetX - this.x;
      var yd = this.targetY - this.y;
      var distToTarget = Math.sqrt(xd * xd + yd * yd);
      if (distToTarget <= this.speed) {
        this.x = this.targetX;
        this.y = this.targetY;
        this.targetX = this.targetY = null;
      } else {
        xd /= distToTarget;
        yd /= distToTarget;
        xd *= this.speed;
        yd *= this.speed;
        this.x += xd;
        this.y += yd;
      }
    }
  },
  draw() {
    ctx.fillText(this.name, this.x, this.y);
  }
}

var enemyList = [];

// to create the player with the shared properties you use Object.assign

var player = Object.assign({}, sharedBehaviour, { // add the unique properties last
  x: 50, // you can overwrite shared properties
  y: 50,
  name: 'P',
  hp: 10
});

// function to create an enemy with the shard properties
// use the for function functionName(  rather than functionName = function
// It is safer and has other benefits as well
// you had enemy = function(id, x, y, spdX, spdY) {
function createEnemy(id, x, y, speed) {
  enemyList.push(Object.assign({}, sharedBehaviour, {
    x,
    y,
    speed,
    id, // You can use shorthand properties rather than x:x,y:y
    name: id,
    setTarget() { // will set the player as a target with a random so its not to hard
      this.targetX = player.x + (Math.random() - 0.5) * 100;
      this.targetY = player.y + (Math.random() - 0.5) * 100;;
    },
    isOnPlayer() {
      var xd = player.x - this.x;
      var yd = player.y - this.y;
      return Math.sqrt(xd * xd + yd * yd) < 30;
    }
  }));
}

function update() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cWidth, cHeight);

  enemyList.forEach(enemy => {
    if (Math.random() < (1 / 300)) { // 1 in 500 chance to look for player about once every 5 seconds
      enemy.setTarget();
    }
    enemy.update();
    if (enemy.isOnPlayer()) {
      // do what you need to do here
      player.hp -= 0.1;
      enemy.x = Math.random() * canvas.width;
      enemy.y = Math.random() * canvas.height;
      enemy.targetX = null;
    }
  })
  player.update();

  // best to update all then draw all
  enemyList.forEach(enemy => {
    enemy.draw()
  });
  player.draw();
  requestAnimationFrame(update);

}
requestAnimationFrame(update);

createEnemy('E1', 150, 350, 60 / 60);
createEnemy('E2', 250, 350, 60 / 60);
createEnemy('E3', 250, 150, 60 / 60);




document.onclick = function(mouse) {
  player.targetX = mouse.clientX;
  player.targetY = mouse.clientY;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500" style="margin: 0 auto; border: 1px solid black;"></canvas>
```

Comment: This is great, I've even printed it out to analize this deeply, thanks a lot :)

Comment: But I'm struggling with another, how to check if mouse is moving ( and do sth ) inside document.onmousedown function? I want to move player to x and y, but when mouse is clicked and hold also to follow x and y of a mouse.